# SQL Select based on difference between two rows

Tags: sql

I am trying to work out how to easily select records based on the difference between two rows.

I have a table like this.

```
Time  | Store   | Code | %      | Ranked |  
------------------------------------------
13:50 | Swindon | 33   | 32.578 | 1      |  
13:50 | Reading | 31   | 29.438 | 2      |  
13:50 | Bath    | 32   | 28.221 | 3      |  
14:50 | Swindon | 33   | 32.100 | 1      |  
14:50 | Reading | 32   | 30.987 | 2      |  
14:50 | Bath    | 32   | 28.335 | 3      |
```

I need to do different reports based on the % difference between the stores at different times.

An example.

Select all stores ranked 1 where `>=` to 3 from the store ranked 2

So in this case it would only select 13:50 Swindon because the difference in % is just over 3%.

There are other variations but I am sure once I have an answer to this I can work out the rest myself.

I know normal select statements but I am thinking I have to do a join but just not sure how.

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear to me. You want to check the interval between the percentage and make a decision on that?

Comment: Please improve your Question. Its very confusing. Your query condition specifies `Ranked` but it hints at `%`.

Comment: A `Join` is used for looking at data from 2 or more tables, you probably just want a `WHERE` condition and an appropriate sort order from what i understand of your question. As Patrick says, it's not very clear.

Comment: Hi Sorry. All stores are ranked at certain time intervals throughout the day based on the % of customers. But I am not sure it actually matters because I want to select all 1st ranked stores where they out ranked other stores by a certain %. So I am guessing that as there is only 1 1st ranked store per time it wouldn't matter. I will not need to query by time just ranking.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information given above I suppose something like this:

```
select *
from table t1
inner join table t2 on t1.Time = t2.Time and t1.Ranked = 1 and t2.Ranked = 2
where (t1.% - t2.%) > 3
```

The column names are a bit off, but I imagine the ranking is based on time.

Comment: Thank you this work fine but in your case and the one below I had to swap the order of the joins to get the 1st ranked from the query. But I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Sorry I have just realised that the query pulls out both records not just 1st ranked, this is the same with the query below as well.

Comment: I don't understand, is it working or not? both queries behave the same

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT R1.store, 
       R1.timestamp 
FROM   store_tbl R1, 
       store_tbl R23 
WHERE  R1.ranked = 1 
       AND R23.ranked = 2 
       AND R1.timestamp = R23.timestamp 
       AND ( R1.percentage - R23.percentage ) > 3
```

Comment: Thank you yours and the query above worked fine except as above I had to swap the order of the From statement.

Comment: Sorry can you give me any further help on the results because it pulls out 1st and 2nd ranked I can not seem to just get the 1st ranked. I have tried to use more AND clauses but this still doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see the "Store" amendment but MS SQL server doesn't seem to recognise that command.